# ASP.NET MVC 4/Web API Single Page App for Mobile Devices ... Needs Authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-web-api

We have developed an ASP.NET MVC 4/Web API single page, mobile website (also using jQuery Mobile) that is intended to be accessed only from mobile devices (e.g., iPads, iPhones, Android tables and phones, etc.), not desktop browsers.  This mobile website will be hosted internally, like an intranet site.  However, since we’re accessing it from mobile devices, we can’t use Windows authentication.  We still need to know which user (and their role) is logging in to the mobile website app.

We tried simply using ASP.NET’s forms authentication and membership provider, but couldn’t get it working exactly the way we wanted.  What we need is for the user to be prompted for a user name and password only on the first time they access the site on their mobile device.  After they enter a correct user name and password and have been authenticated once, each subsequent time they access the site they should just go right in.  They shouldn’t have to re-enter their credentials (i.e., something needs to be saved locally to each device to identify the user after the first time).

This is where we had troubles.  Everything worked as expected the first time.  That is, the user was prompted to enter a user name and password, and, after doing that, was authenticated and allowed into the site.  The problem is every time after the browser was closed on the mobile device, the device and user were not know and the user had to re-enter user name and password.

We tried lots of things too.  We tried setting persistent cookies in JavaScript.  No good.  The cookies weren’t there to be read the second time.  We tried manually setting persistent cookies from ASP.NET.  No good.  We, of course, used FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true); as part of the form authentication framework.  No good.  We tried using HTML5 local storage.  No good.  No matter what we tried, if the user was on a mobile device, they would have to log in every single time.  (Note: we’ve tried on an iPad and iPhone running both iOS 5.1 and 6.0, with Safari configure to allow cookies, and we’ve tried on Android 2.3.4.)

Is there some trick to getting a scenario like this working?
Or, do we have to write some sort of custom authentication mechanism?  If so, how?  And, what?
Or, should we use something like claims-based authentication and WIF?
Or???

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: cookies are the way to do it, are you sure the device you are testing with allows cookies?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I believe cookies are allowed.  For example, on the iPad that I'm testing with, if I go to Settings > Safari > Accept Cookies, I have it set to Always.  Then if I go to Settings > Safari > Advanced > Website Data, I can see what appears to be the cookie.  However, that cookies and it's authentication information is not read/used in any subsequent visits to the site.  And, I'm not sure how to make this work.

Comment: Is the cookie set to persistant? and do you have a static machine key for that web application?

Comment: Thanks for the info./questions.  The cookie is set to persistent.  However, we don't have a static machine key set for the web app.  Is that required?  I read something about setting a machine key in the web.config file but was unsure if I really needed to do that (I've never done this type of web app before, I come from an ASP.NET web forms w/ Windows auth and desktop browsers background).

Comment: the key means if the web application is restarted it can still decrypt the old cookies.

Answer (score 0):

try adding .browser file as discussed here:
http://www.simonantony.net/knowledge-base/articles/browsing-your-site-on-an-iphone-using-chrome-does-not-work/

I know it says chrome, but i've accountered this problem with safari also.